# Traffic monitoring tools for IIS server?

Tags: iis, performance, iis-7.5, asp.net

We are planning to optimize IIS server.We are doing load testing of 20 concurrent user and want to see the bottleneck. How to monitor each request/response times? and check where is the bottleneck?

Is there any documentation for IIS optimizing and performance? If loadtest fails tuning IIS server kind of.?

Comment: IIS Capacity Analysis? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282/en-us

Answer (score 0):

New Relic is expensive, but does what you are asking for. You can run a free trial for a short period of time (which should be long enough to solve any immediate problems).